# Reload div content after form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax

My form submits using:

```
onsubmit='umce();ut();reloadResponses(); return false;'
```

These functions are:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {             
        reloadResponses();
    });//doc ready

    function reloadResponses() {

        $("#manualReload").attr({
          disabled: "disabled",
          title: "10 second timeout"
        });
        $('#manualReload').html('<i class="icon-time"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Please wait...');
        $('#ajaxnews').load('pages/news/comments-load.php?newsid=<?php echo $newsid;?>&RandomNumber=' + Math.random());

        setTimeout (function(){
            $("#manualReload").attr({title: "Click to reload comments"});
            $("#manualReload").removeAttr("disabled");
            $('#manualReload').html('<i class="icon-refresh"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Reload Comments');
        },10000);
    }

    //Collect data from TinyMCE and POST the data to the PHP comment processor via AJAX.
    function umce(){ 
       tinyMCE.get("comments").save(); 
       tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');
    };


    function ut(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            type:"POST", 
            url:'pages/news/comments-add.php', 
            data:"text="+encodeURIComponent($("#comments").val())               
        }); 
    return false;};
```

Everything works fine, the TinyMCE content is collected and saved to the database, but `reloadResponses();` doesn't fully work after form submission. It blanks the DIV (#ajaxnews)  but fails to complete the .load function? I almost want to 'refresh' the division by calling the .load on the PHP file again, but it just returns a balnk result. Am I missing anything obvious?

Also, I know the code can be massively optimised, and I know that I can turn off caching using ajaxsetup, but I will study all of that once I get the script working. Thank you!

Comment: The data being returned is perfect.

Comment: try to print the value `pages/news/comments-load.php?newsid=<?php echo $newsid;?>&RandomNumber=' + Math.random()`, whats the value in it, then put that address directly in browser window and see what you get?

Comment: Hi @Ummar, I did exactly that and it's fine, the content is perfect.

Comment: @KirkBeard Hi Kirk, I could but it would honestly not be worth it, it's simply a list of comments left by users pulled straight from the DB.